# Vue Router Setup work when visited directly via URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking for advice on how to go about this routing scenario:

I have the following HTML that loops category and items in the category. The `<router-view>` is inside the category so that when an item is clicked it will open only in the category that related to that item.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="cat in categories">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="business in filteredByCat">{{business.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <router-view v-if="..."></router-view>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My routes are as follows:

```
{
      path: '/businesses',
      name: 'Directory',
      component: Directory,
      children: [{
        path: ':listing',
        name: 'Listing',
        component: Listing
      }]
    }
```

Visualization:

[image: layout visualization]

How do I get the data of the item clicked to pass to the `router-view`? I assume I'd use props but that wouldn't work if the user visited details directly by URL?

I tried getting the item like so:

```
methods: {
    finalItem ($route) {
      var match = this.businesses.filter((business) => {
        return business.link === $route.params.listing
      })
      return match[0]
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work, even if it did, this feels wrong. Is there a way to pass the data in a way that would preserve even when visited directly? This is my primary concern. (I understand the repeated `<router-view>` is bad code but am not sure how to get around doing that with my layout. Open to suggestions on that too though.)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, having a `<router-view>` component within a `v-for` block isn't a great idea. Why exactly do you need a router within there, would a component not suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll look into a better option with the `router-view`. The reason I have a router is so the user can go to `website.com/businesses` and `website.com/businesses/listing` `/businesses` would be the repeated list mentioned above. `/businesses/listing` would show details of the individual businesses that was clicked.

Comment: Would the 'listing' part in the `website.com/businesses/listing` path be a parameter? i.e. the URL could really look like this, `website.com/businesses/82718`, or would it be an absolute path?

Comment: Exactly, the URL would be a human readable name for the path parameter. Example: `website.com/businesses/businessShortName`

Comment: Cool, in that case you definitely only need one `router-view` instance, probably defined somewhere _higher up_ and nearer the 'root' of your main template/render function. For most Vue apps I have developed, it is __very__ rare to ever use more than one `router-view`. From there, you simply just define two routes, one of what the `website.com/businesses/` page looks like (Just populate with `router-link`'s to the relevant path), and another route with what the `website.com/businesses/:listing` looks like, which can obviously be defined by data from some sort of API call or database lookup.

Comment: @varbrad, I edited an image of my layout into my question.  Not certain but perhaps it is one of those rare cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using `router-view`, you might as well just drop a component in.  As far as using multiple `router-view`s goes, it's **very** common, so idk what @varbrad is talking about there. Child routes are fine.

The not-so-common part is using multiple `router-view`'s in one component. The UI you're aiming for is nearly identical to Netflix. If you check out what they're doing, you'll see that they pass a movie ID (business id/shortname) as "jbv" and a row number (category name) as "jbr" in the route query.

Let's mimic this in your component:

I'm not sure what `filteredByCat` looks like, but the way you have it set up, it would list the same businesses for every category. Try something like this:

```
computed:{
  businessesByCategory(){
     let dictionary = {};
     this.businesses.forEach(business=>{
       business.categories.forEach(category=>{ // assuming each business has an array of categories
         dictionary[category] = dictionary[category] || [];
         dictionary[category].push(business)
       })
     })

     return dictionary;
  }
},
data(){
  return {
    activeBusiness:null
  }
},
methods:{
  setActiveBusiness(business){
    this.activeBusiness = business;
  },
  setUrlQuery(listing, category){
    this.$route.query.listing = listing;
    this.$route.query.category = category;
  },
  openListing(business, category){
    this.setActiveBusiness(business);
    this.setUrlQuery(business.link, category);
  }
}
```

-

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="cat in categories">
        <ul>
            <li 
              v-for="business in businessesByCategory[cat]"
              @click="openListing(business, cat)"
             >                     
                 {{business.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <Listing :business="activeBusiness" v-if="$route.query.category == cat"></Listing>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks perfect! Will test ASAP!

Comment: Everything is working except that the route doesn't update (and hence, causing the `v-if` to not work) I assume that has something to do with `setUrlQuery`? Correct me if I'm wrong, but this wouldn't update URL like so? `businesses/businessShortName` This is vital for me as I need my users to be able to go directly to one of them businesses without needing to go through the business page first and many of the links exist in the wild already in this format.

Comment: It's fine if you leave the business part as a parameter, but conventionally speaking, businesses can belong to more than one category, so you'll want to pass the category as a query to maintain state. Another option would be to just display the business in a different context on reload. This is what Netflix and Instagram do. Essentially, you could check if a business is in the URL then check if there is an active category. If there is not category active, just show the business in a standalone section on the top of the view.

Comment: & My mistake on the `setUrlQuery` function. I misread something. You have to use `$router.push` or `$router.go` whenever you update the route.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That does sound like the best path forward.